# How to convert a big decimal to hex in bash?

Tags: bash, hex, decimal

I need to convert a very big number in its hex form (no spaces, no anything e.g. 8ac7230489e80001). Using `printf` gives an out of range error.

```
printf '%x\n' "24267339429148234667523"

-bash: printf: warning: 24267339429148234667523: Numerical result out of range
ffffffffffffffff
```

I tried other methods (python), but it seems they only give a string output. I still need it to be a number.
Is it possible to handle numbers larger like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `bc` utility:

```
bc <<< 'obase=16;24267339429148234667523'
```